# Android Version Change from 2.2 to 4.2.2

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with changing the android version for the application. I have made in the "Package Explorer" under the Project saying Android 2.2 but I have tried on some higher version like 4.2.2 and it is not working but when I try on 2.2 it works without any problems.
I tried to change the version via Right Click on the project > Properties > Android > Android 4.2.2 but that didn't work either. Here is my sdk:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

On 4.2.2 I am getting below thing in log :

> 09-28 02:27:13.088: W/System.err(785):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   09-28 02:27:13.088: W/System.err(785):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   09-28 02:27:17.708: I/System.out(785): onpause loginauthactivity.......
>   09-28 02:27:17.718: I/System.out(785): inside homeButton() .......
>   09-28 02:27:18.178: I/Choreographer(785): **Skipped 121 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>
>   09-28 02:27:19.918: I/Choreographer(785): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>
>   09-28 02:27:20.318: I/Choreographer(785): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.**
>   09-28 02:27:22.738: I/System.out(785): inside menu_login

Code Snippet in one of my class:

public class LoginAuthActivity extends Activity {

```
private Button login;
private EditText username;
private EditText password;
private String user = null;
private String pwd = null;
private String status = null;
private boolean flag = false;
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
boolean logged;

//class variables
AppEngineDAO ackDAO;
AlertDialogManager alert = null;
SessionManager session = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //set the layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_auth);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Inside LoginAuthActivity onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

    //creating object of the classes
    ackDAO = new AppEngineDAO();
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    alert = new AlertDialogManager();


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editusername);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
    login.setOnClickListener(loginButtonListener);

}

private OnClickListener loginButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Inside loginButtonListener OnClickListener()",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        System.out.println("INSIDE login BUTTON .....");

        displayError();

        if (flag == false) {
            user = username.getText().toString().trim();
            pwd = password.getText().toString().trim();
            System.out.println("inside flag false.....");
            try {
                status = ackDAO.login(user, pwd,"student");
                System.out.println("status in login auth....." + status);
                if (status.equals("ok")) {
                    System.out.println("inside STATUS OK.....");
                    session.createLoginSession(user, pwd);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            HomeActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("user", user);
                    startActivity(i);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
                } else if (status.equals("notok")) {
                    System.out.println("inside STATUS notOK.....");
                    alert.showAlertDialog(LoginAuthActivity.this,
                            "Login failed..",
                            "Username/Password is incorrect", false);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Maybe post the relevant code?

Comment: You didn't say what is "not working". The warnings you are getting are just warnings (though they might lead to visible ANR warnings onscreen), and they are probably caused by `ackDAO.login` being synchronous, i.e. blocking the main thread for hundreds of milliseconds (possibly way longer) while some kind of network request is performed. If you are getting NetworkOnMainThreadExceptions, well, there's the problem. Make the network stuff async and it goes away (or just disable that check, but that would be knowingly ignoring your mistakes).

Comment: When I click on login button I am not getting any response.....application just stays as it is.......Infact On all of the buttons I am getting same problem

Answer (score 0):

Seeing log it seems you are doing some heavy operation in the main thread. After changing the android version to 4.2 try to clean your project, no need to change sdk version manually in manifest or properties file.

Comment: In eclipse below clean under Project tab you will see "Build Automatically". If its not checked it and try to clean again.

Comment: Then there might be chance that your sdk version 4.2 is not completely downloaded, if so try to install it completely using sdk manager and also tools and adt.

Comment: I checked twice this things are completely OK